# How can I understand the algorithm behind a Ezmix EQ/COMP preset?

Tags: recording, homerecording

I've bought a model of Line 6 POD HD500x and I've almost found out a cool preset.
The problem is that I've added a ezmix eq/comp preset at the end (on Reaper), and it's not the same without that.
The preset is : Guitar Bus

I've tried to compare the signal spectrum before and after the plugin but I can only notice a band compression and I know for sure that a COMP and a EQ has been applied. Do you know some tricks to reproduce almost the same algorithms?

Thanks

Comment: Can you change your question to be more clear?  You will never know the algorithm unless you get the source code.  You can speculate, sure. Do you perhaps want to just know what is conceptually being done to the sound?  If that is the case, then I still think you should clarify because you did, in a very sophisticated way (spectrum analysis), already learn that, you discovered band compression, so, why are you not happy with your results?  That's not clear.

Comment: Also, you say that you detected "band compression" after a compressor and EQ was applied.   But that is exactly what those effects do together: they accentuate frequencies (a band) then squash it (compress), so, what am I missing, what are you still looking for.